# Can "in the ground" or "underground" substitute for "in the earth" in this phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here is an explanation for the word, "lode".

> lode -a vein of metal ore such as gold or silver, that is found **in the earth**

I wonder whether **in the earth** in the text can be replaced with words from the below list of choices.

- **on the earth**
- **on the ground**
- **in the ground**
- **underground**

Comment: In the ground or underground, as these things usually aren't above ground, are the best choices. A load is literally a seam of an ore that is mined for production. While there are both open pit and underground mines, the lode is still not on the surface. It must be mined.

Comment: *lode not load. above. Sorry

Comment: In English you would try to avoid a phrase like "that is found in/on the ground" unless you are writing a song lyric. The meaning is OK, but English prose style usually avoids repeated rhythms and rhymes, unless they are intentional and add something to the meaning. "That is found underground" is OK, because the stress is on the first syllable of "underground", which breaks up the rhythm and rhyme of "found" and "ground". (Compare the song lyric "I'm a mole and I live in a hole"!)

Comment: @Giambattista Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Giambattista stated in the comment to your initial question, both **“in the ground”** and **underground** work. However, underground has a host of commonly used meanings dealing with activity and subversion that make “in the ground” preferable. Consider that the [definition of underground at Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/underground) includes #3 (*adj.*):

> existing, situated, operating, or taking place beneath the surface of the ground.

It would be common to talk about a military bunker, a storm shelter, a subway, or wires/cables being *underground*. However, it would be more common to refer to a stake, or a rock, or a fox’ den as being *in the ground*.

I don’t mean to add confusion when I say that a (gold or other metal ore) mine would far more often be referred to as underground. And if the ore was taken from that mine (shaft) the vein or lode would more likely be called underground in that circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

"On" is on the surface.

”In the ground" suggests close to the surface, in the soil for example.

"Underground" is the most suitable of your suggestions, but sounds quite unscientific compared with the original "in the earth".

If referring to Earth as a planet, "found on Earth" would be appropriate.

Comment: Um, there's no difference between *in the ground* and *underground* at all. None.

Comment: For me there is: whatever 'the ground' is, one is in it and the other is under it. For me the ground is the stuff we walk on

Comment: Um, no. That's not correct at all. Whatsoever. When we bury people, we say we *put them in the ground*. They're literally 6 feet under the ground; they're certainly not sticking out of it.

Comment: And a metro system or aquifer are in the ground or underground?

Comment: While I wouldn't use in the ground for then subway, I certainly would refer to an aquifer as being *in the ground*. You're trying to add nuance where there is none. Refer  back to my casket example; is it merely stuck in the ground or under it?